# Автоматический подсчет

Tags: php, javascript

На странице есть форма с 3 полями: Price, Amount, Total. Как сделать, чтобы после ввода Price и Amount, Total подсчитывался автоматически по какой-либо формуле?

Comment: покажите что уже есть и что вы хотите

Comment: @Manitikyl к сожалению нет ничего т.к по идее средствами php это не сделать без перезагрузки, мне нужно чтобы поле total, после ввода первых двух полей подсчитывалось автоматически, допустим ввел я price= 20, amount =2, и мне сразу выдало в поле total 40

Comment: А если в поле amount нужно ввести 22? После ввода "2" в поле total отобразится сначала 40, а после добавления еще одной двойки 440. Это нормально?

Comment: @Vincent Да, это то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  function recalculate(price, amount) {
    if (!price || !amount) {
      $('#total').val('');
      return;
    };
    
    let total = price * amount;
    $('#total').val(total);
  };
  
  $('#price, #amount').on('input', () => {
    let price = $('#price').val(),
      amount = $('#amount').val();
      
    recalculate(+price, +amount);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

price: <input id="price"> <br>
amount: <input id="amount"> <br>
total: <input id="total" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input id="price" type="text" name="">
  <input id="amount" type="text" name="">
  <input id="total" type="text" name="">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var price=document.getElementById("price");
    var amount=document.getElementById("amount");
    var total=document.getElementById("total");

    price.addEventListener("input",calc);
    amount.addEventListener("input",calc);

    function calc(){
      total.value=price.value*amount.value;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: При вставке через контекстное меню не будет работать

Comment: Согласен, исправил. Думаю, автору вопроса важно понять принцип, а функцию он уже напишет на свой вкус. Добавит проверку введенных данных и тд...